# Searching for a sad scene from a cartoon where a little kid is trying to heal their already dead parent

Tags: story-identification

I only vaguely remember, but it was probably an anime and if I remember correctly a little girl had some healing cream that was said to heal almost anything. She tried to heal her already dead mom or dad or I'm not even sure if it was an actual family member but she tries to heal her loved one while not realizing that it's helpless and it's all super tragic.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? Where did she get the healing cream from? How did the family member die? What else happens in the cartoon/anime? Can you remember any of the plot? If you remember anything else please [edit] your answer to include those extra details.

Comment: When did you see it? Where were you (region / country)? Was the animation from the same place. Did it seem to be contemporary to the time you saw it or earlier? Was there an obvious style (Anime, Russian, Western . . .). Please add anything you can remember, it will help us help you :)